# How to use the build pipeline to deploy azure data factory resources?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have a Azure data factory to deploy using azure devops. So I have created a build pipeline using the "Publish Build Artifacts" task and created the artifacts folder named "drop" which has the resources i want to deploy.

I need help with the release pipeline for the same. Which task should i use in my release pipeline to deploy this artifact folder "drop"?

I initially tried with ARM template deployment but it doesn't make use of the drop folder and deploys everything i.e, the entire data factory everytime. So i created a build folder wherein i have only limited things to deploy. But i am now stuck with the release pipeline task for the same.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: If you have a build pipeline to generate the artifact, then you can add the generated artifact directly to the release pipeline which you can check the doc [Artifact sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#sources). Or , choose the `Azure Repos Git` and select the source manually. Am i misunderstanding the requirement?

Comment: I can add the artifact.As the link you mentioned, i have already gone through that, and the artifact is added. but for release pipeline to work, we need some task which will help to deploy that artifact in the next stage right? That task i want to know here. because for ADF deployment, i always see "resource group deployment task" . But it does not help the cause actually.

Comment: @YangShen-MSFT can you provide some help on this?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. If you are looking for ways to pass artifacts between your release pipeline stages, you can use the `PublishPipelineArtifact` and `DownloadPipelineArtifact` task, check [Publish and download artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and you will see these tasks can *share files between stages in a pipeline*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use version 2 of RG deployment:

[image]

And then you need to select, Create or Update Resource Group.

You need to provide path of ADF ARM templates in the template path text box.

Thanks,

Pratik

Comment: Actually i dont want to use the ARM template deployment method because then there is no use of creating the build pipeline.